# How to change error.localizedDescription to JSON by Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In Swift I got the error from Cloud Functions.
And I caught the error like this

```
functions.httpsCallable("addMessage").call(["text": inputField.text]) { result, error in
  if let error = error as NSError? {
    if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
      let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
      let message = error.localizedDescription
      let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
    }
  }
}
```

The message get like JSON format from Cloud functions.
`{"message":"text is required","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}`

If I got the error message from Cloud functions, and I want to display to the user.
First I tried
`let status = message["status"]`
But I got `No exact matches in call to subscript`  in xcode.
How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: `localizedDescription` returns always a plain string.

Comment: I got the error `{"message":"email is required","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}`  from cloud functions. I want to set like this.
`self.error = "email is required".  ` How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`error.localizedDescription` is obviously a JSON string, you have to deserialize it

```
let messageJSON = error.localizedDescription
let messageDictionary = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String:String].self, from: Data(messageJSON.utf8))
let message = messageDictionary?["message"] ?? ""
```